# How to configure webpack for Angular2 tests?

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-jasmine

How to configure webpack for Angular2 tests ?

I have set up webpack based configuration for testing Angular2 npm package.
Anyway i keep getting errors like:

> Error: This test module uses the component PaginationComponent which is using a "templateUrl", but they were never compiled. Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test. in karma-test-shim.js (line 9952)

And in my opinion i did everything right, and it should work. The `html` and `scss` file should be loaded by webpack.

If you want to check full configuration, i have uplaoded it to [GitHub](https://github.com/Vardius/ng2-pagination/tree/4b3989634fd058f651673a5129262e1c0d761cd4). You can find there `webpack.test.js`, `karma.conf.js`, `package.json` along with project source. It is small - one component project.

For full error messages you can go to [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/Vardius/ng2-pagination/jobs/164574283)

Here is my `webpack` configuration:

```
var path = require('path');
var _root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'null'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: root('src'),
                loader: 'null'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: root('src'),
                loader: 'raw'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: root('src'),
                loader: 'null'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: root('src'),
                loader: 'raw!postcss!sass'
            }
        ]
    }
};

function root(args) {
    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return path.join.apply(path, [_root].concat(args));
}
```

Comment: One problem in see is the `_root`. You are resolving by `'..'` going up. In the Angular example, they have the `helpers.js` file in a `config` folder. So the root would be a level up. But in your case, you just copied the content from the helper file into your config file, which is already at the root. So you should really only use a single dot `'.'`. Haven't really figured out it this fits in at all with the problem. But the problem seems to be that the template file can't be found, so maybe it _is_ related. I don't know. I'm not too fluent in webpack

Comment: @peeskillet you are right but this is not this :(

Comment: So I created [a repo](https://github.com/psamsotha/angular2-webpack) based on the Angular documentation. Tested it, and it worked. So I stripped it down to more fit your project structure, and tested it, and it still works. I tried some different things to try and break it, but couldn't really find anything really different from yours that would cause it to break. Maybe you may have better luck :-/

Comment: Maybe it because we have different `tsconfig.json` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with TypeScript configuration.

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "isolatedModules": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "exclude": [
    "components.d.ts",
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/browser",
    "node_modules",
    "examples"
  ]
}
```

The option `"declaration": true` whih triggers the generation of the typings *.d.ts files, that enable IDE Intellisense was cousing the webpack to throw errors during the tests.

I resolved this by commenting out this line when testing and uncommenting when running `build`.